# Vue created hook: rendering different data based on localStorage keys

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a dashboard, where for explanation purposes, can show open tickets OR closed tickets. I separated them into two API calls.

If the `withClosed` argument is set to 0, show open tickets. If set to 1, show closed tickets.

```
getTickets: function (region, withClosed=0) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

The created hook:

```
created: function () {
    this.getTickets(this.region, 0);
}
```

If I want to show closed tickets, I just set `withClosed` to 1 instead of 0. Shows the tickets. No issue there.

`localStorage` is where I'm getting tripped up. If closed tickets are displayed, I do the following in the `mounted()` hook:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('savedClosedTickets')){
  this.closed_tickets = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedClosedTickets'));
}
```

To be clear, the `savedClosedTickets` key is set via `setItem` in a watcher for `closed_tickets`.

If I check out Chrome dev tools, `closed_tickets` is indeed true which is what I want:

[image: localStorage savedClosedTickets key]

However upon refresh of the page, it shows the open tickets, and this is of course because of what's in the `created` hook.

I've toyed with the `beforeCreate` and `beforeMount` hooks but to no avail. I've tried doing an `if/else getItem()` in the `created` hook but it keeps showing the open tickets on refresh.

What is the appropriate way to tackle this?

Comment: There's not enough context to reproduce the issue. Can you link to a reproduction (e.g., in codesandbox)?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with the following. Oddly enough localStorage `removeItem` wasn't removing the item if it's a bool, just sets it to false. So checked against that in the created hook. Slightly dirty:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('savedClosedTickets') === "true"){
  // render closed tickets
} else if (localStorage.getItem('savedClosedTickets') === "false"){
  // render open tickets
} else {
  // falls here on initial load (no pairs set), so render open tickets
}
```

And in the method for showing closed tickets, if toggle isn't enabled (clicked, checked, etc), then removeItem:

```
localStorage.removeItem('savedClosedTickets');
```